# Visual C# creating list of items

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, user-interface

I need to make an application that shows codes that update from time to time. 
Now I got the back-end part covered but I am completely new to the front end part.

I'd basicly like it took look something like this:
[image]

Now the idea is that I'll have a List that holds items that should be converted to elements in the below visual list.. The logo is something I staticly added and that is anchored to the left top corner, I'd like to create the rest of the elemnents dynamically (I have a timed event loop to check if the list has changed, etc)

So I made the following method as a starting point:

```
 private void createOTPEntry()
    {
        Rectangle entry = new Rectangle();
        entry.Name = "entry1";
        entry.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 111, 0));
        entry.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(243, 86, 13));
        entry.Height = 65;
        entry.Width = 497;
        Thickness margin = entry.Margin;
        margin.Left = 10;
        margin.Top = 83;
        entry.Margin = margin;
        entry.BringIntoView();
    }
```

Now this isn't relative yet to the logo or anything.. But it's supposed to atleast be a white rectangle with an orange border.. And it's not showing. I tried to find if my rectangle object has like a "show" or "draw" method but it doesn't.. And I'm still miles away from what I really want..

So the logic of what I want:

- Loop that goes over list elements and draws the visual list elements, probably a Rectangle containing 2 TextBoxes or Labels (one of the labels will change)
- These elements will be added to another Container? that has a scrollbar in case there are to many elements.

I'd like some help of possible on what control do I choose to add the elements to? (the container witht he scrollbar?). How exactly do I show my rectangle? Is there an easy way to make them kinda automaticly space when I add them to the "parent control" (the scrollable container).

Thanks in advance for giving me a jump start!

Comment: Have you looked into WPF in any great detail yet? What's your background with GUI programming? For a C# program I would create a WPF application, then you can use xaml to do everything you've got in your code there already. Maybe have a look at something like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt149842(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: check this: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/ and http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/

Comment: @simonalexander2005 my backgorund in GUI programming is 0. I'm an engineer.. It's a crypto application and I need to add a GUI msyelf. I'm already doing it in WPF but I assumed that the drag and drop wouldn't be sufficient since the amount of elements will be dynamic (according to a list I'll load in code)

Comment: Yes. The way to do it would typically be to create the list of data in the C# code, then to use something called databinding in the XAML code to link the list to the code behind. A "Data Template" can be used to format the list like you show in the diagram. The question is probably too broad to give a full answer - but hopefully that's some topics to get you started.